# How to define route in Sinatra for AngularJS html5Mode

Tags: ruby, angularjs, sinatra, angularjs-routing

Here is my code in Sinatra:

```
get '/' do
  @title = 'AngularJS html5Mode: true'
  haml :main
end
```

And AngularJS:

```
  angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/sweets/:id', {
      templateUrl: '/sweet.html',
      controller: 'SweetCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

This works perfect, but after reloading page with `/sweets/1` url, Sinatra throws exception because url was changed on client side by AngularJS and Sinatra can't find url path, which is absolutely correct behaviour for Sinatra. Now the question is how to handle this types of exceptions in Sinatra? Which route should I define? Please note that I still need Sinatra to throw exceptions in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow all the routes in sinatra same as your angular route configuration. So,

```
get '/' do
  @title = 'AngularJS html5Mode: true'
  haml :main
end
get '/:id' do
  @title = 'AngularJS html5Mode: true'
  haml :main
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For me it is a duplication in code, which seems to be hard to maintain in future. Is there any method to sync them both?